# Guzzle: Parallel file download using Guzzle's Pool:batch() and `sink` option

Tags: php, guzzle, guzzle6

You can execute http requests in parallel using Guzzle's `Pool:batch()` method. It allows you to set default options for requests using `options` key in the third parameter.

But what if I need different options for different requests in the pool? I would like to execute GET requests using a pool and stream each response to a different file on disk. There is a `sink` option for that. But how to apply different values of this option to requests?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Rastor's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40467700/3348774) is almost right, but it's incorrectly implemented if you want to provide "options" to the `Pool()` constructor.

He's missing the critical implementation of the Pool options array mentioned [here](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/Pool.php#L16).

The Guzzle docs say:

> When a function is yielded by the iterator, the function is provided
> the "request_options" array that should be merged on top of any
> existing options, and the function MUST then return a wait-able
> promise.

Also, if you look at the `Pool()` code below the comment I linked to, you can see that Guzzle's Pool calls the callable and gives it the Pool's "options" as the argument, precisely so that you are supposed to apply it to your request.

The correct precedence is

> Per-request options > Pool options > Client defaults.

If you don't apply the `Pool()` object's options array to your request objects, you will end up with severe bugs such as if you try making a `new Pool($client, $requests(100), ['options'=>['timeout'=>30.0]]);`. Without my corrected code, your Pool-options won't be applied at all, since *you* didn't support merging the pool options properly and therefore simply ended up discarding them.

So here is the correct code with support for `Pool()` options:

```
<?php

$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

$requests = function ($total) use ($client) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
        $url = "domain.com/picture/{$i}.jpg";
        $filepath = "/tmp/{$i}.jpg";

        yield function($poolOpts) use ($client, $url, $filepath) {
            /** Apply options as follows:
             * Client() defaults are given the lowest priority
             * (they're used for any values you don't specify on
             * the request or the pool). The Pool() "options"
             * override the Client defaults. And the per-request
             * options ($reqOpts) override everything (both the
             * Pool and the Client defaults).
             * In short: Per-Request > Pool Defaults > Client Defaults.
             */
            $reqOpts = [
                'sink' => $filepath
            ];
            if (is_array($poolOpts) && count($poolOpts) > 0) {
                $reqOpts = array_merge($poolOpts, $reqOpts); // req > pool
            }
            
            return $client->getAsync($url, $reqOpts);
        };
    }
};

$pool = new Pool($client, $requests(100));
```

Note however that you don't have to support the `Pool()` options, if you know that you will never be adding any options to your `new Pool()` constructor. In that case, you can just look at [the official Guzzle docs](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html?highlight=pool#concurrent-requests) for an example.

The official example looks as follows:

```
// Using a closure that will return a promise once the pool calls the closure.
$client = new Client();

$requests = function ($total) use ($client) {
    $uri = '127.0.0.1:8126/guzzle-server/perf';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
        yield function() use ($client, $uri) {
            return $client->getAsync($uri);
        };
    }
};

$pool = new Pool($client, $requests(100));
```

Comment: how do you get back the correct index in in that case ? let´s say instead of $total you use an arrray $a['a'] = 'url', $a['x'] = 'url' and so on. how to you know which request result belongs to which array key of $a ?

Answer (score 1):

For guzzle 6

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

$requests = function ($total) use ($client) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
        $url = "http://domain.com/picture/{$i}.jpg";
        $filepath = "/tmp/{$i}.jpg";

        yield function() use ($client, $url, $filepath) {
            return $client->getAsync($url, [
                'sink' => $filepath
            ]);
        };
    }
};

$pool = new Pool($client, $requests(100));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the `$options` you want on the requests individually. It would only apply to all requests if you pass it to the client. Here's the excerpt from Guzzle 6 doc:

> Headers may be added as default options when creating a client. When
>   headers are used as default options, they are only applied if the
>   request being created does not already contain the specific header.
>   This include both requests passed to the client in the send() and
>   sendAsync() methods and requests created by the client (e.g.,
>   request() and requestAsync()).

See http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/request-options.html?highlight=default#headers

Comment: It works for all requests at once. I need separate $options for each request to download each response body into a separate file.

Comment: If you put the $options array on the Request object, it will only apply to that request... I reworded my sentence

Comment: The question was about using the Pool, not separate `Request` objects ;)

Comment: You have to create your Request object anyway... And pass them to the pool. I found your question while looking for an answer on my questions, check how I create a batch of Request and them pass them to the batch method : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32323140/file-not-closed-on-request-complete-using-guzzle-5-3/32332072#32332072