# Guzzle6 error Invalid resource type: array when send a GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request

Tags: php, guzzle, guzzle6

I am trying to send a code by using GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request,somehow I get error  Invalid resource type: array, the following is my codes

```
$params = ["name"=>"myName","id"=>"myId"];
$client = new Client();
$request = new Request('PUT','https://api.hitbox.tv/media/live/myName?authToken=myToken',["content-type"=>'application/json'],["json"=>$params]);

$response = $client->send($request);
```

I'm following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36492389/6516422) guide.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to use JSON in the request, just create it with `json_encode()`:

```
$request = new Request(
    'PUT',
    'https://api.hitbox.tv/media/live/myName?authToken=myToken',
    ["content-type" => 'application/json'],
    json_encode($params)
);
```