# Array and Guzzle

Tags: php, symfony

Having a problem with guzzle and json in a symfony console app, my code looks like this:

```
$client = new Client([
    'timeout' => 15,0,
]);

$body =[
    "revision" => "1",
    "changelog" => "stuff",
    "description" => "Testing",
    "user" => "Foo bar",
];
var_dump(json_encode($body));

$request = new GuzzleRequest('POST', "https://api.newrelic.com/v2/applications/$appId/deployments.json", array(), ['deployment' => json_encode($body)]);

$response = $client->send($request, ['headers' => ['X-Api-Key' => $apiKey]], ['timeout' => 200]);
```

The response I get is:

```
 Invalid resource type: array
```

Comment: HAve a look to your logs and paste the full error code.

Comment: There is nothing in the log regarding this.

Comment: It seems it should be `$request = new GuzzleRequest('POST', "https://api.newrelic.com/v2/applications/$appId/deployments.json",  ['deployment' => json_encode($body)]);` ?

Comment: No, that array is needed there (it is for header).

Comment: For curl it is this:

`
      curl -X POST 'https://api.newrelic.com/v2/applications/someappid/deployments.json' \
           -H 'X-Api-Key:somkey' -i \
           -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
           -d \
      '{
        "deployment": {
          "revision": "1",
          "changelog": "stuff",
          "description": "Testing",
          "user": "Mikke"
        }
      }'

`

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38633068/guzzle6-error-invalid-resource-type-array-when-send-a-guzzlehttp-psr7-request

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38633068/guzzle6-error-invalid-resource-type-array-when-send-a-guzzlehttp-psr7-request) (Guzzle6), **you must specify content-type**, try :

```
$client = new Client([
    'timeout' => 15,0,
]);

$body = [ 'deployment' => [ 
             "revision" => "1", 
             "changelog" => "stuff", 
             "description" => "Testing", 
             "user" => "Foo bar", 
           ] 
        ];

$request = new GuzzleRequest('POST', "https://api.newrelic.com/v2/applications/$appId/deployments.json", ["content-type"=>'application/json'], json_encode($body));

$response = $client->send($request, ['headers' => ['X-Api-Key' => $apiKey]], ['timeout' => 200]);
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: What is the version of Guzzle you use ?

Comment: Try to send json_encode($body) as the last parameter

Comment: Tha last parameter is json_encode($body) - or am I missundersatnding you?

Changed code a bit, but same problem.



``$body = [
   'deployment' => [
  "revision" => "1",
  "changelog" => "stuff",
  "description" => "Testing",
  "user" => "Foo bar",
   ]
 ];


 $client = new Client([
   'timeout' => 15,0,
 ]);
 
 $request = new GuzzleRequest('POST', "https://api.newrelic.com/v2/applications/$appId/deployments.json", array(), ['json' => $body]);
 $response = $client->send($request, ['headers' => ['X-Api-Key' => $apiKey]], ['timeout' => 200]);\

Answer (score 0):

Got it sorted:

```
$body = ['deployment' => [
    "revision" => "1",
    "changelog" => "stuff",
    "description" => "Testing",
    "user" => "Foo bar",
  ]];


$client = new Client([
  'timeout' => 15,0,
]);

$request = new GuzzleRequest(
  'POST',
  "https://api.newrelic.com/v2/applications/$appId/deployments.json",
  ["content-type" => 'application/json'],
  json_encode($body)
);
$response = $client->send($request, ['headers' => ['X-Api-Key' => $apiKey]], ['timeout' => 200]);
```