# swagger php client int[] type/syntax error

Tags: php, arrays, swagger

I am using a php client generated with swagger codegen 2.3.1. also tried 2.4.0_snapshot, still has the same error.
the swagger.json used for generation can be found [here](https://esi.evetech.net/latest/swagger.json)

I am trying to use a generated post function that has one parameter of type `int[]`.

according to the generated documentation it should be used like this

```
$apiInstance = new Swagger\Client\Api\UniverseApi();
$ids = array(new \Swagger\Client\Model\int[]());
$datasource = "tranquility";
$result = $apiInstance->postUniverseNames($ids, $datasource);
```

if i define `$ids` like that, it give me a `syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'`

If I make `$ids` an array, eg.:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(96305152)
  [1]=>
  int(96075776)
}
```

it throws an exception:

> Exception: Invalid resource type: array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out is was a guzzle problem and nothing with the generated client.
It's similar to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38633068/guzzle6-error-invalid-resource-type-array-when-send-a-guzzlehttp-psr7-request),
simply encode the array as json:

```
$ids = json_encode(array(new \Swagger\Client\Model\int[]()));
```

or

```
$result = $apiInstance->postUniverseNames(json_encode($ids), $datasource);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `$ids = array(new \Swagger\Client\Model\int());` ?

Comment: that leads to `uncaught error: class 'swagger\\client\\model\\int'` not found

Comment: Also check without the backslash after new

Comment: Same error. I am also not seeing an int class being generated anywhere by swagger